# Jquery Form Validation - Required Field Error

Tags: jquery, validation

I struggle for long hours to display error messages under input fields in a form. What I  am trying to do is, show an error message when an input is left empty. I could find a sample on internet but I could not get it work as i want . I added an extra input field which has "sur_contact_name" id. But there is no error message regarding this input. It did not work out somehow. can anyone help me please to solve the issue. Here is the code exported to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/allence/zK7pn/3/

HTML code for input fields:

```
 <div>
            <label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name"></input>
            <span class="error">This field is required</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Name -->
        <div>
            <label for="sur_contact_name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="sur_contact_name" name="surname"></input>
            <span class="error">This field is required</span>
        </div>
```

Thankss..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have posted the complete code in your question.
The question will become meaningless if the jsfiddle link goes away.

Based on the code you have in jsfiddle you've got a couple of issues.
Quick fix:
Change

```
<div>
    <label for="sur_contact_name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="sur_contact_name" name="surname"></input>
    <span class="error">This field is required</span>
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
   <label for="sur_contact_name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="contact_surname" name="surname"></input>
   <span class="error">This field is required</span>
</div>
```

and eliminate the jquery code you added to validate surname

```
        <!--Name can't be blank-->
        $('#sur_contact_name').on('input', function() {
            var input=$(this);
            var sur_name=input.val();
            if(sur_name){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
            else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
        });

    for (var input in form_data){
        var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
```

because the name validation will handle it as well...